# Is list::size() really O(n)?

Tags: c++, list, big-o, std, complexity-theory

Recently, I noticed some people mentioning that `std::list::size()` has a linear complexity.
According to [some](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/size.html) [sources](http://bytes.com/forum/thread60248.html), this is in fact implementation dependent as the standard doesn't say what the complexity has to be.
The comment [in this blog entry](http://ahlamnote.blogspot.com/2006/11/stl-list-size-method-is-slow.html) says:

> Actually, it depends on which STL you
>   are using. Microsoft Visual Studio V6
>   implements size() as {return (_Size);
>   } whereas gcc (at least in versions
>   3.3.2 and 4.1.0) do it as { return std::distance(begin(), end()); } The
>   first has constant speed, the second
>   has o(N) speed

1. So my guess is that for the VC++ crowd `size()` has constant complexity as Dinkumware
   probably won't have changed that fact since VC6. Am I right there?
2. What does it look like currently in `gcc`? If it is really O(n), why did the
   developers choose to do so?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Pre-C++11 answer

You are correct that the standard does not state what the complexity of `list::size()` must be - however, it does recommend that it "should have constant complexity" (Note A in Table 65).

[Here's an interesting article by Howard Hinnant](http://howardhinnant.github.io/On_list_size.html) that explains why some people think `list::size()` should have O(N) complexity (basically because they believe that O(1) `list::size()` makes `list::splice()` have O(N) complexity) and why an O(1) `list::size()` is be a good idea (in the author's opinion):

- http://howardhinnant.github.io/On_list_size.html

I think the main points in the paper are:

- there are few situations where maintaining an internal count so `list::size()` can be O(1) causes the splice operation to become linear
- there are probably many more situations where someone might be unaware of the negative effects that might happen because they call an O(N) `size()` (such as his one example where `list::size()` is called while holding a lock).
- that instead of permitting `size()` be O(N), in the interest of 'least surprise', the standard should require any container that implements `size()` to implement it in an O(1) fashion.  If a container cannot do this, it should not implement `size()` at all.  In this case, the user of the container will be made aware that `size()` is unavailable, and if they still want or need to get the number of elements in the container they can still use `container::distance( begin(), end())` to get that value - but they will be completely aware that it's an O(N) operation.

I think I tend to agree with most of his reasoning.  However, I do not like his proposed addition to the `splice()` overloads.  Having to pass in an `n` that must be equal to `distance( first, last)` to get correct behavior seems like a recipe for hard to diagnose bugs.

I'm not sure what should or could be done moving forward, as any change would have a significant impact on existing code.  But as it stands, I think that existing code is already impacted - behavior might be rather significantly different from one implementation to another for something that should have been well-defined.  Maybe onebyone's comment about having the size 'cached' and marked known/unknown might work well - you get amortized O(1) behavior - the only time you get O(N) behavior is when the list is modified by some splice() operations. The nice thing about this is that it can be done by implementors today without a change to the standard (unless I'm missing something).

<s>As far as I know, C++0x is not changing anything in this area.</s>

Comment: The answer is correct but the reasoning on the size of list is flowed. Your proposal is prone to inconsistent parameters and violate the principle of having the user to give every information only once.

Comment: Should also be possible to keep splice O(1), but mark the size as "unknown". Then size() is still O(N) worst-case, but the worst case occurs at most once per 'unfriendly' splice. So performance of all operations is strictly superior to an always-O(N) size(). Warning: I have not thought this through.

Comment: "strictly superior" - actually that's a lie, since there are some extra checks in splice to figure out what case you're in, and arithmetic with sizes in all mutators. Told you I hadn't thought it through. But complexity is never worse, and sometimes better.

Comment: @PierreBdR - In case it's not clear, I'm not the author of the paper, I pointed to it because I thought it had some interesting points.  I have edited the answer to make that more clear (as well as adding some more of my own thoughts and incorporating ideas from these comments).

Comment: The latest C++0x draft requires that `size()` have constant time complexity (that change to the container requirements was made in N3000).

Answer (score 87):

In C++11 it is required that for *any* standard container the `.size()` operation must be complete in "constant" complexity (O(1)). (Table 96 — Container requirements). Previously in C++03 `.size()` *should* have constant complexity, but is not required (see [Is std::string size() a O(1) operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256033/is-stdstring-size-a-o1-operation)).

The change in standard is introduced by [n2923: Specifying the complexity of size() (Revision 1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2923.pdf).

However, the implementation of `.size()`  in libstdc++ still uses an O(N) algorithm in gcc up to 4.8:

```
  /**  Returns the number of elements in the %list.  */
  size_type
  size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
```

See also [Why is std::list bigger on c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065055/why-is-stdlist-bigger-on-c11) for detail why it is kept this way.

***Update***: `std::list::size()` is [properly O(1)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49561#c20) when using gcc **5.0** in C++11 mode (or above).

---

By the way, the `.size()` in libc++ is correctly O(1):

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT     {return base::__sz();}

...

__compressed_pair<size_type, __node_allocator> __size_alloc_;

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
const size_type& __sz() const _NOEXCEPT
    {return __size_alloc_.first();}
```

Comment: this should be accepted, unfortunately ppl dont look at old Q. :)

Answer (score 15):

I've had to look into gcc 3.4's `list::size` before, so I can say this:

1. It uses `std::distance(head, tail)`.
2. `std::distance` has two implementations: for types that satisfy *RandomAccessIterator*, it uses "tail-head", and for types that merely satisfy *InputIterator*, it uses an O(n) algorithm relying on "iterator++", counting until it hits the given tail.
3. `std::list` does not satisfy *RandomAccessIterator*, so size is O(n).

As to the "why", I can only say that `std::list` is appropriate for problems that require sequential access.  Storing the size as a class variable would introduce overhead on every insert, delete, etc., and that waste is a big no-no per the intent of the STL. If you really need a constant-time `size()`, use `std::deque`.

Answer (score 13):

I personally don't see the issue with splice being O(N) as the only reason why size is permitted to be O(N). *You don't pay for what you don't use* is an important C++ motto. In this case, maintaining the list size requires an extra increment/decrement on every insert/erase whether you check the list's size or not. This is a small fixed overhead, but its still important to consider.

Checking the size of a list is rarely needed. Iterating from begin to end without caring the total size is infinitely more common.

Comment: Apparently the C++11 committee didn't agree with you. Pity.

Answer (score 5):

I would go to the [source](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221183042/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html)). SGI's STL page says that it is permitted to have a linear complexity. I believe that the design guideline they followed was to allow the list implementation to be as general as possible, and thus to allow more flexibility in using lists.

Comment: SGI isn't exactly the "source".  It is based on the original (HP?) STL, but the Standard deviated from that.  SGI's merely says what their implementation does, not what the Standard says it's supposed to do.

Comment: And the link's broken now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers mentioned C++11 and GCC, but not mention _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI compile definition in GCC, this is not enough

1. Compiled with -std=c++11 do not mean std::list::size() is O(1) in GCC, it's default O(1), but when compiled with _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0, it's O(N)
2. GCC version < 5.1, like GCC4.8 support C++11, but std::list::size() is O(N) no matter you use what compile flags.
   .

This can be clearly be shown in current GCC [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h):
size() is implement as below

```
  _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
  size_type
  size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return _M_node_count(); }
```

It called _M_node_count(), and _M_node_count is implemented as below:

```cpp
    #if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
      static size_t
      _S_distance(const_iterator __first, const_iterator __last)
      { return std::distance(__first, __last); }

      // return the stored size
      size_t
      _M_node_count() const
      { return this->_M_get_size(); }
#else
      // dummy implementations used when the size is not stored
      static size_t
      _S_distance(const_iterator, const_iterator)
      { return 0; }

      // count the number of nodes
      size_t
      _M_node_count() const
      { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
#endif
```

if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI is set to 0, the size() is O(N), in other case is O(1).
_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI set to 0 will happen when you use a high version GCC compiled libraries and need link to a low version GCC compiled libraries, for example, your system have installed a GCC 4.8 compiled GTEST libraries, but your code now use GCC 7.3 and use C++11, and you need to link to that libraries, in this case you need to add following to your CMakeLists.txt, otherwise it will have link issue.

```
add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

In a word, in GCC,

- When using GCC version < 5.1, std::list::size() is O(N)
- When using GCC version >= 5.1:

  - when compiled with _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0, std::list::size() is   O(N)
  - when compiled without _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI set(default is 1) or with _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1,
    std::list::size() is O(1)

Answer (score 1):

This bug report: [[C++0x] std::list::size complexity](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49561), captures in excruciating detail the fact that the implementation in GCC 4.x is linear time and how the transition to constant time for C++11 was slow in coming (available in 5.0) due to ABI compatibility concerns.

The manpage for the GCC 4.9 series still includes the following disclaimer:

> Support for C++11 is still
>   experimental, and may change in incompatible ways in future releases.

---

The same bug report is referenced here: [Should std::list::size have constant complexity in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19154205/86967)

Answer (score 0):

If you are correctly using lists you aren't probably noticing any difference.

Lists are good with big data structures that you want to rearrange without copying, of for data you want to keep valid pointers after insertion.

In the first case it makes no difference, in the second i would prefer the old (smaller) size() implementation.

Anyway std is more about correctness and standard behavious and 'user friendlyness' than raw speed.

Comment: I'm not clear on how wanting to know, in a pinch, how many elements are in a list, constitutes not using a list properly.