# Efficiency of c++ built ins

Tags: c++, documentation, performance

I am fairly new to C++, having much more C experience.

I am writing a program that will use the string class, and began to wonder about the efficiency of the "length()" method.

I realized though that I didn't have a good answer to this question, and so was wondering if the answer to this and similar questions exist somewhere. While I am more than capable of determining the runtime of my own code, I'm at a bit of a loss when it comes to provided code, and so I find I can't accurately judge the efficiency of my programs.

Is there c++ documentation (online, or in "man" format) that includes information on the runtime of provided code?

Edit: I'm interested in this in general, not just string::length.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256033/is-stdstring-size-a-o1-operation

Comment: It should be noted... you should use string::size() instead of string::length() because all other STL containers use size() only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present, time complexity of `size()` for *all* STL containers is underspecified. There's an [open C++ defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#632) for that.

The present ISO C++ standard says that STL containers *should* have `size()` of constant complexity:

> #### 21.3[lib.basic.string]/2
>
> The class template basic_string conforms to the requirements of a Sequence, as specified in (23.1.1). Additionally, because the iterators supported by basic_string are random access iterators (24.1.5), basic_string conforms to the the requirements of a Reversible Container, as specified in (23.1).
>
> #### 23.1[lib.container.requirements]/5
>
> - Expression: `a.size()`
> - Complexity: (Note A)
>
> Those entries marked ‘‘(Note A)’’ **should have constant complexity**

However, "should" is not a binding requirement in the Standard parlance; indeed, the above applies to `std::list` as well, but in practice some implementations (notably g++) have O(N) `std::list::size()`.

The only thing that can be guaranteed is that `(end() - begin())` for a string is (possibly amortized) O(1). This is because string iterators are guaranteed to be random-access, and random-access iterators are guaranteed to have constant time `operator-`.

As a more practical issue, for all existing C++ implementations out there, the following holds:

- `std::string::size()` is O(1)
- `std::vector::size()` is O(1)

They are fairly obvious, as both strings and vectors are most efficiently implemented as contiguous arrays with separately stored size: contiguous because it gives fastest element access while satisfying all other complexity requirements, and storing size is because Container requirements demand that `end()` be constant-time.

Comment: "possibly amortized O(1)". Amortized over what?

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly phrase it, but I was thinking about `std::deque` - and the general implementation approach (linked list of vectors) when I wrote that; in theory, a standard-compliant string could use deque or something similar as underlying storage.  

But come to think of it, I'm not even sure that deque iterators have O(1) `operator-` for iterators, amortized or not (though the Standard requires them to). Anyone care to compute the complexity for it?

Comment: deque iterators are random access too, and that means they have O(1) operator- by definition. Any implementation that does otherwise is faulty, but you can't draw any other conclusions. It's not too hard to implement this since operator[] needs to be O(1) as well. So, in general you can efficiently calculate x-y as (x-begin())-(y-begin()).

Comment: I fail to see how `deque` iterators can be O(1), given that to iterate from one to another can require iterating over several linked clusters of items - i.e. in effect iterating over a linked list - which is definitely not O(1). I believe that `operator[]` for `deque` is only _amortized_ O(1) as well, for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

All of the implementations I've seen are O(1).

The documentation you're looking for is the C++ standard -- I believe C++03 is the latest one at present. It isn't available online or in man format, it's sold commercially. There's a list of the places to find it, and recent prices, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard/83763#83763).