# How can I do a binary search on a part of the keys in a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, containers, binary-search

I have a map of data; the key is `std::string`. I want to perform a binary search on it, but I cannot just use `std::map::find()`, because I will provide only a part of the key.

Let's say I have a map with the following keys:

```
["abc"] -> ...
["efg"] -> ...
["ijk"] -> ...
["iik"] -> ...
```

I want to search through this with, let's say providing only `"i"`, and the search should return:

> ["ijk"] -> ...,    ["iik"] -> ...

Is this possible? I have tried to do this using iterators, but I failed, as I cannot treat them as indexes.

Note: I keep the data in a map, because of other reasons, so I don't want to change it into a different data structure.

Comment: As usual, show what you actually have tried n a small code sample!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but you wouldn't need to actually binary-search through the data.

You can use [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) to find the first element and then advance the resulting iterator until your key no longer matches your criteria, storing them in a `<vector>` or similar container to return them all.

Comment: `lower_bound` is a binary search :)

Comment: I'd like to think of that binary search as an implementation detail :)

Comment: OK, technically speaking the words "binary search" aren't in the standard; I'll give you that. But given the requirements placed on that function it can't really be anything else.

Comment: While `std::map` commonly is implemented using a red-black (binary) tree, I don't see a strong reason why `map` must be a **binary** tree.

Comment: May want to mention `is_transparent` which can make this more efficient and/or practical for some types.

Answer (score 3):

[`map::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) will help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I built a solution based on [`map::lower_bound()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) as suggested by [lccarrasco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121744/2675154) and [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121724/2675154). This function provides an iterator to the first element in your map you are looking for. The function performs a binary search as its complexity is logarithmic in size.

Then you have to advance the provided iterator as long as the string you are looking for is a prefix of the values in your map. [One way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054031/2675154) of doing this is using [`string::compare()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

For the sake of clarity I have chosen `int` as value of your map. Please replace it with the type of your data. All in all the code looks as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::map <std::string, int> myMap{ {"abc", 1}, {"efg", 2}, {"ijk", 3}, {"iik", 4} };
    std::string prefix("i");

    for (auto it = myMap.lower_bound(prefix); it != std::end(myMap) && it->first.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0; ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> iik -> 4
>   ijk -> 3

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/NdxpXt)