# Is there any function in C++ std::string that count total number of same starting characters of two strings or any best way to do

Tags: c++, string, function, count, stl

Eg.

```
abcfgf
abdef
```

ans=2 {"ab" is a common starting character}

Comment: There's nothing with asking precise questions like this, imho. We should all strive to maximise our use of standard library functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if one string is a prefix of another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913835/check-if-one-string-is-a-prefix-of-another)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Except, the C++ Standard Library does provide such a function.  You have to be very careful when claiming something doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), which returns a pair of iterators indicating the respective iterators where sequences start to differ.

To count the length of common prefixes, for example, you could do the following:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string l = "abcde", r = "abcdfgh";
    cout << distance(begin(l), mismatch(begin(l), end(l), begin(r)).first) << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba :-) Thanks

Comment: Learned something new today. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @AmiTavory it shows
error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope|
error: 'end' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: @r_ranjan Are you compiling this in c++11 mode? In any case, you could switch `begin(l)` with `l.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a buildin function to do this, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953747/2411320).

However, you could do it by simply using a loop (if you want, but would not suggest it), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 = "abcfgf";
    string str2 = "abdet";

    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.size() && i < str2.size(); ++i)
        if(str1[i] == str2[i])
            counter++;

    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2