# How to improve time complexity of this code?

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity

How can I improve the time complexity of this code??

```
 $s = "Name";
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) {

    //some code

    }
```

Comment: This is not so complex,why do you think that?

Comment: You do realize this for loop is the fastest of all iterating loops?

Comment: Sorry, was thinking javascript. Still, a basic for loop is still very fast. You're performing microoptimizations at this point

Comment: Unless you're modifying the length of `$s` inside the loop, then use `$lenS = strlen($s); for($i=0; $i<$lenS; $i++) { //some code

}`; and as a further micro-optimisation use `++$i` rather than `$i++`

Comment: Without knowing the problem it's impossible to guess an algorithm.

Comment: But what is `// some code`? You're more likely to be able to find optimisations in that than you are in execution of the looping mechanism

Comment: @MarkBaker OP's code has a complexity of O(n). Why do you think your's is better in terms of time complexity?

Comment: @Markus - #1.... no overhead of calling the `strlen()` function in every iteration of the loop; #2 no need for a temporary variable at opcode level if you preincrement rather than postincrement (depends on version of PHP). Neither changes the time complexity of the algorithm, they simply generate more efficient opcode; but OP isn't showing any algorithm anyway

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch How can I optimize the for loop? Since I am using the function strlen() in for loop, would it affect the time complexity??

Comment: @MarkBaker It was an interview question. I answered exactly what you did except for the pre and post-increment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on PHP's implementation of Strings and `strlen()`. If it is O(n) (which it is in GNU's C `strlen()`) the complexity of OP's code would be O(n²). Moving the `strlen()` out of the loop would improve to O(n) in this case:

```
$length = strlen($s);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {

//some code

}
```

---

However if the complexity of `strlen()` is O(1) ([e.g. C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256033/is-stdstring-size-a-o1-operation)), The code is in O(n) and you can't improve it any more.

I have to admit, that I'm not fluent in C/C++, but I guess the length is a simple attribute of a [`zend_string`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5d7ccb758b407d1ba6bc7502b22ebb7cfcd2912c/Zend/zend_string.c), i.e. [PHP's `strlen()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L524) is O(1):

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(strlen)
{
    zend_string *s;
    // [..]
    RETVAL_LONG(s->len);
}
```

Comment: You're right in that strlen() is O(1) in core PHP. Moving the call to strlen() out of the loop won't change the time complexity, only reduce the overhead of n function calls to a single function call is an implementation detail