# Does using size() function of string inside a recursive function results in large delay/complexity?

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity

I was implementing different versions of a recursive function that checks whether a string is a palindrome and calculating complexities for them, but was confused about passing the string size as a parameter or calculating it using `size()` function and store it in a variable created inside the function, which would be more efficient?

Here's an Example of the 2 versions of the function:

```
bool isPalindrome1 (string s) {
    int sz = s.size();            // size calculated and stored
    if (sz < 2) return true;
    return ((s[0] == s[sz-1]) && isPalindrome1(s.substr(1, sz-2)));
}
```

and,

```
bool isPalindrome2 (string s, int sz) {    //size passed as parameter
    if (sz < 2) return true;
    return ((s[0] == s[sz-1]) && isPalindrome2(s.substr(1, sz-2), sz-2));
}
```

The first function would obviously take more time "time needed for `size()` function to return the size" but would this be of a significant delay if the original string size was kinda large? how's the complexity here calculated?

Note: I know this isn't the most efficient way to check recursively if a string is a palindrome, I'm just trying to better understand complexity and recursion.

Comment: *but would this be of a significant delay if the original string size was kinda large?* -- No, a string knows its size.  There is nothing to calculate or count.

Comment: ..in contrast to strlen and a “C NUL-terminated string”..

Comment: The `substr` isn't cheap. If you're worried about efficiency I'd get rid of that too.

Comment: You're passign the string by value, that will slow you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11, `std::string::size()` has [constant complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). Before that, its complexity [was recommended to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256033/is-stdstring-size-a-o1-operation) ("should") be constant, and I know of no compilers that would not follow this recommendation.

In practice, the string size value is either already stored in the `string` object or calculated as a difference between two stored pointers.