# Why std::equal crashes if second vector empty

Tags: c++, vector, std

I am using `std::equals` defined in `<algorithm>` to check if two vectors are equal. It crashes when second vector is empty. I could avoid crash by checking if second vector is empty, but is there a reason to not include the check in `equal` function itself ?

Sample code:

```
std::vector<int> a;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) a.emplace_back(i);

std::vector<int> b;
for (int i = 0; i < 0; ++i) b.emplace_back(i);

std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

Comment: You are using the wrong overload, the one you are calling requires that the last parameter refers to a container that has at least as many elements as the first container

Comment: Because the iterator in b goes out of range. equal does not check the sizes of the containers just iterates (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457072/c-stdequal-rationale-behind-not-testing-for-the-2-ranges-having-equal-siz)

Comment: Just use : (a==b)  it is implemented for vectors  and does check the sizes of the containers too. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Comment: Here is an example program with a [mcve]: [https://ideone.com/q7kQ13](https://ideone.com/q7kQ13)

Comment: @UnholySheep I didn't find any other overload on https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/. Only other overload requires specifying comparison function. Can you point out the overload to use ?

Comment: @user10439725 cplusplus.com is not a good reference site, prefer using cppreference.com: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `std::equal` with 3 arguments, which in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal says:

> Returns true if the range [first1, last1) is equal to the range
> [first2, first2 + (last1 - first1)), and false otherwise

which will cause undefined behavior in you case

Use `std::equal` with 4 arguments instead:

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

which will do:

> Returns true if the range [first1, last1) is equal to the range
> [first2, last2), and false otherwise.

which is what you want.

Or, you can just use operator `==`. `std::vector` overloads one:

```
a == b;
```

Answer (score 3):

The range (as the number of comparisons) of compared elements in this call

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

is specified by the first two arguments `[a.begin(), a.end() )`. But this range is invalid for the vector `b`.

Use this form of the algorithm

```
template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
bool equal(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2);
```

where ranges are specified separately for the both compared containers as

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```