# Do gcc and clang STL implementations violate rules about allocator?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

In 23.2.1p3 C++11 Standart we can read:

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an `allocator_type`, objects stored in these components shall be constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` function and destroyed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` function (20.6.8.2). These functions are called only for the container’s element type, not for internal types used by the container. [ *Note*: This means, for example, that a node-based container might need to construct nodes containing aligned buffers and call `construct` to place the element into the buffer. —*end note* ]

`allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` just call passed allocator's `construct` method, if allocator defines one. I tried to use this and create allocator, which use list-initialization for construction, so I can utilize `emplace` for aggregate initialization:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
struct init_list_allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
    template<typename... Args>
    void construct(T* p, Args&&... args)
        { ::new((void *)p) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}; }

    // Fix copy-constructors usage for aggregates
    void construct(T* p, T& copy_construct_arg)
        { std::allocator<T>::construct(p, copy_construct_arg); }

    void construct(T* p, const T& copy_construct_arg)
        { std::allocator<T>::construct(p, copy_construct_arg); }

    void construct(T* p, const T&& copy_construct_arg)
        { std::allocator<T>::construct(p, std::move(copy_construct_arg)); }

    void construct(T *p, T&& move_construct_arg)
        { std::allocator<T>::construct(p, std::move(move_construct_arg)); }
};

template<class T>
using improved_vector = std::vector<T, init_list_allocator<T>>;

struct A {
    int x;
    double y;
    const char* z;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> strings;
    improved_vector<A> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i) {
        strings.emplace_back(to_string(i*i));
        v.emplace_back(i, sqrt(i), strings.back().c_str());
    };
    for (const auto& elem : v)
        cout << elem.x << ' ' << elem.y << ' ' << elem.z << '\n';
}
```

However, at least in gcc and clang, this doesn't work. The problem is, that their implementations of `vector` use `Allocator::rebind<T>::other::construct` instead of `Allocator::construct`. And, because of our inheritance from `std::allocator`, this `rebind` gives `std::allocator<T>::construct`. Ok, no problem, just add

```
template<typename U>
struct rebind {
    using other = init_list_allocator<U>;
};
```

in our allocator's definition and this code will work. Great, now let's change `vector` to `list`. Here we have the unsolvable problem, because instead of `Allocator::construct` object is initialized inside `std::_List_node<_Tp>` constuctor in direct-initialization form (form with brackets).

Are this 2 issues a standard violations or I miss something?

Comment: The first issue is clearly not a violation -- the whole purpose of the nested rebind struct is to allow containers to allocate "wrappers" where necessary. Pretty much every container except `vector` has to do this. I don't see anywhere in the standard that prohibits standard library implementations from using direct initialization for the second case, but the first reference I had for this turned out to be incorrect, so I've deleted my answer for now.

Comment: For the first issue: i think, in this paragraph standard says that container should use `allocator_type::construct` for objects construction, where `allocator_type` for every container is defined as `typedef Allocator allocator_type`, where `Allocator` is container's template parameter. So it's ok to use `rebind` for obtaining memory, but not for our object construction. Am I wrong?

Comment: It may be a bug in libstdc++, yes. The bit you cited seems to indicate that.

Comment: Aside: C++ was not designed around requiring inheritance for everything. Inheritance is a very close coupling relationship and typically, to use it properly, the inherited class needs to be designed with it in mind and the inheriting class needs to have a very good understanding of the parent class. Inheriting from `std::allocator` is not necessary to implement an allocator and the class was not particularly designed for it. This is one case where you probably should not be using inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have found the answer myself and want to provide it.

For the first issue (using `Allocator::rebind<T>::other::construct` instead of `Allocator::construct`), my first allocator implementation (second one is OK) doesn't satisfy `Allocator` requirements in part of `rebind`, see 17.6.3.5 Table 28:

> ```
> +------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
> |    Expression    | Return type | Assertion/note pre-/post- condition |
> +------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
> | typename         | Y           | For all U (including T),            |
> | X::template      |             | Y::template rebind<T>::other is X.  |
> | rebind<U>::other |             |                                     |
> +------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
> ```

For the second issue: GCC has old, pre-C++11 implementation of std::list, which will be fixed only in GCC 5.0, because this change breaks ABI (see [Should std::list::size have constant complexity in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154205/should-stdlistsize-have-constant-complexity-in-c11) for more info)

However, the quoted standard requirement, that container must call `construct` function for **exactly** `allocator_type` and not for some rebinded type seems like a standard defect (http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2218). Libstdc++ implementations of `std::set`, `multiset`, `map` and `multimap` rely on this fact and use rebinded allocator for construct (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64096).

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, libstdc++ and MSVC++ are correct here. The point of `rebind` is, as the note indicates, that containers may be required to construct things that are not `T`. For example, `std::list<T>` needs to construct a list node containing `T`, not `T`. Similar cases exist for the associative and unordered containers. That's why the `rebind` structure exists in the first place. Your allocator was nonconforming before that was in place.

---

For the second issue, your reference

> These functions are called only for the container’s element type, not for internal types used by the container.

seems to indicate that standard library implementations aren't allowed to call `construct` for rebound allocators, however. This may be a bug in libstdc++.

---

As for the actual solution to this problem, give `A` a constructor that has the behavior you want, and don't bother with allocators for this purpose. People may want to create instances of `A` outside of a container with the special allocator:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int x;
    double y;
    const char* z;
    A() = default; // This allows A to still be a POD because the default constructor
                   // is not "user-provided", see 8.4.2 [dcl.fct.def.default]/4
    A(int x_, double y_, char const* z_) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) {}

};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> strings;
    vector<A> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i) {
        strings.emplace_back(to_string(i*i));
        v.emplace_back(i, sqrt(i), strings.back().c_str());
    };
    for (const auto& elem : v)
        cout << elem.x << ' ' << elem.y << ' ' << elem.z << '\n';
}
```

Comment: For the first issue, please, watch my comment above. For your solution, I wanted to create something generic, which can work for any aggregate type.

Comment: @Bevel: For the first issue, I stand by what the answer says. You must provide `rebind`. Calling `construct` through the rebound allocator (the second issue) is likely nonconforming, but calling any other member of the rebound allocator is perfectly conforming.

Comment: Yea, I understand that, but because here my allocator doesn't implement any tricky memory allocation technique, I was ok for inherited `rebind` behaviour, just want `construct` call from my allocator. The issue, which I don't agree, is `construct`calling through `rebind`, I'm pretty fine with `rebind` itself.