# std::list.begin() slows down for bigger lists

Tags: performance, list, c++11, stl

I have following problem. I need to implement LexBFS algorithm which has to use double linked list. I chose `std::list` . When I finally debugged my code I've noticed strange behaviour - list operations slows down as list grows. I narrowed down to this one line:

```
// start new iteration
clock_t tbegin = clock();
if(L.size() && L.begin()->empty) {
  double ee = double(clock() - tbegin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cerr << fixed << setprecision(6) << "t: " << ee << " size: " << L.size() << "\n";
  //...
}
// here I make other operations on L...
```

`L` is `std::list<Class>` where `Class` is my simple struct with a few fields.

This is the output:

```
t: 0.000086 size: 5224
t: 0.000124 size: 7818
t: 0.000281 size: 17515
t: 0.000300 size: 19310
t: 0.000341 size: 21202
t: 0.000406 size: 25117
t: 0.000459 size: 29202
t: 0.000510 size: 31307
t: 0.000528 size: 33413
t: 0.000562 size: 35487
t: 0.000638 size: 39740
t: 0.000706 size: 41885
t: 0.000710 size: 44037
t: 0.000747 size: 46261
t: 0.000868 size: 52670
t: 0.000982 size: 54800
t: 0.000957 size: 56895
t: 0.001084 size: 58993
t: 0.001114 size: 61101
```

Simple lookup slows down! What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Compilation flags:

```
clang++ a.cpp -o ./a -std=c++11 -Wall -g 

Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: I would guess it's std::list::size that's causing your timing results... Or not. Since C++11 it must be constant complexity.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228908/is-listsize-really-on

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/size/

in C++98, list.size( ) is not required to be O(1)

try compiling in C++11 mode

Comment: I use -std=C+11.

Comment: you will need GCC 5+, because they kept O(n) size for std::list a bit longer than desired because of an ABI break   https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx