# Loop end condition with iterators and custom step size

Tags: c++

I am adding some functionality to a previously built code. I have to loop over a list is steps of 2 and process the elements elements differently.

Here's my attempt.

```
for(auto list_it = std::next(list.begin()); list_it != list.end() ; std::advance(list_it,2)){

   // Do something

}
```

I am initializing `list_it` to point to the second element using `next(list.begin())`
Each iteration it moves forward by 2 `advance(list_it,2))`.

**[Q]**

I am unsure how to test the loop exit condition.

`list_it != list.end()` might not work if we skip over `list.end()` when advancing forward by 2.

Is there any standard way to deal with this issue? I might check skipped iterators for being `list.end()`, but I don't see this as a nice, scalable way with larger step sizes. (unless it turns out to be the only way).

Comment: You **can't** skip over `list.end()`, it will be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to prevent that.

Comment: How about checking whether :  iter != list.end() && (iter+1) != list.end() ? That should work.

Comment: @E.N.D, `std::next(iter)` instead of `iter + 1`. List iterators are not random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : Modifying for generic size.

For step size of k, You can get size of List in O(n) or O(1) - depending upon C++ compiler. After that compute steps you're allowed to take by:

```
  size_t steps_allowed = list.size()/k; 
   // list.size() is O(n) for C++98 and O(1) for standard C++ 11.
```

Then loop over another variable `i` and inside loop termination condition check for `i` against `steps_allowed`.

Comment: `std::next(list_it) != list.end()` isn't going to help since you are increasing by `std::advance(list_it,2)`

Comment: Loop will terminate because upon advancing by 2, `list_it` will fall on `list.end()`, wouldn't it?

Comment: It could, or it could be one past the end.  Remember, the OP is looking for a generic solution, not for just if the step is `2`.

Comment: Oops, Let me modify it for generic one.

Comment: In standard C++11, `std::list::size()` [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228908/is-listsize-really-on) `O(1)`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't advance past the `.end()` iterator. You have to use either a counter, or check all intermediate iterators. For example:

```
template<class It>
void checked_advance(It& it, It last, std::size_t n) {
    while (n-- > 0 && it != last)
        ++it;
}

assert(!list.empty());
for (auto it = std::next(list.begin()); it != list.end(); 
     checked_advance(it, list.end(), step)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change you condition to check and make sure the difference between the current iterator and the end iterator is more then the step amount.  That would look like

```
for(auto list_it = std::next(list.begin()); 
    std::distance(list_it, list.end()) > step; 
    std::advance(list_it, step))
{

// Do something
}
```

Comment: It looks like `O(N)` traversal is now `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @Evg `O(2N)` no?  I'm advancing the current iterator twice, not the from the beginning every time.

Comment: But `std::distance` has to traverse the list, too. At each step it makes `O(N)` iterations.

Comment: @Evg Yeah, but it's traversing from `list_it` so you only do `step` traversals.

Comment: @Evg Oops, nevermind, I get it.  I'll still leave it as an option

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might do:

```
for (auto& e : list | ranges::view::drop(1) | ranges::views::stride(2)) {
    // e
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will stick to the standard library for now though