# search top n% of a vector member C++

Tags: c++

let's define

```
struct A
{ 
int m;
...
}

std::vector<A> vec; //a large vector (magnitude of million members)
```

I am interested to find top 2% member of **vec** where the members have highest value in their **m** method.

For that I was thinking something like this:

```
std::multimap<int, A> top_members;

const auto nr_top = std::lround(vec.size() * 0.02);
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
  if(top_members.size() == nr_top + 1)
    top_members.erase(std::prev(top_members.end()));
  else
    top_members[it->m] = *it
  }
```

Do you think of any faster solution?

Comment: When you say "top 2%", do you mean 2% of the total number of vector entries?

Comment: Is `vec` already sorted? Otherwise your solution only gets the **first** valid 2%, not the **top** 2%

Comment: To get the top `k` elements without sorting, one solution is to use a `min-heap` of `k` items.  So if you know `k`, then you have a solution.

Comment: Is it okay if you rearrange the elements in the vector?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: [All containers have O(1) size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751799/15416) so `k` is just `vec.size()/50`. But I think you need a max-heap, not a min-heap.

Comment: To get the top K, a min-heap would be used.  (I know it sounds counter-intuitive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) has a complexity of `n log m` where `n` is the number of elements and `m` is the number elements you want sorted. You can use this to sort **just** the top 2%.

```cpp
const auto nr_top = std::lround(vec.size() * 0.02);
std::partial_sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + nr_top, vec.end(),
  [](auto a, auto b){return a > b}
);
// the top 2% will be at the front of the vector
```

If you need the top 2% in a different container, you can use [`std::partial_sort_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) instead.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want `partial_sort`. It will sort 2% of your items, and the remaining 98% will be in essentially random order.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the vector and the elements inside are not already sorted, you can make use of [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void nth_element( RandomIt first, RandomIt nth, RandomIt last,
                  Compare comp );
```

> `nth_element` is a partial sorting algorithm that rearranges elements in [first, last) such that:
>
> - The element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) were sorted.
> - All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.
>     ...
>
> **Complexity**: Linear in `std::distance(first, last)` on average.

So that, given a `std::vector<A> v`, in your case you could write

```
size_t top_two = std::llround(v.size() * 0.02);

std::nth_element(v.begin(),
                 v.begin() + top_two,
                 v.end(),
                 [](A const& a, A const& b){ return b.m < a.m; });
```